# Good cross browser player for video ads on website

Tags: jquery-plugins, html5-video, ads

I am looking for a good video player to display video ads on my site. We want to make these ads in standard IAB sizes. I would like to use html5 when possible, and have a fall back for browsers that do not support it.

The player needs to have a onclick function that can be set or overwritten so that a person clicking on the ad will be taken to a page for the ad.

I tried setting up HTML5 video tags and giving it a onclick event shown below, but the flash file I used for fallback does not work with the onclick event.

```
<script>
$('video').click(function() {    window.open('http://mydomain.com','_newtab');
});
</script>
```

Does anyone know of a good player for this?

Comment: why not use the native video player of a browser and style it to your needs?

Comment: Even if you provided some code...you're still asking for an external library/tool/resource...

Comment: When you say native vdeo player, do you mean the <video> tag, or somthing else? We still get some traffic from older browsers like IE 7 that do not support it.